# What would cause the ajax request to not fire?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ok so i have this jQuery

```
$('.remove_me').click(function(){
    var value = $(this).attr('title');
    console.log('In here');
    console.log(value);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "/shop_pos/index.php?route=module/cart/ajax_remove_item",          
        dataType: 'json',
    data: {value : value},
        success: function (data) {
        },  
        complete: function () {                 
        }           
    });
    console.log(value);

});
```

And in the console in firebug the console.logs display but there is no outgoing ajax request..I even tried this and still nothing

```
$('.remove_me').click(function(){
    var value = $(this).attr('title');
    console.log('in here');
    console.log(value);
    $.getJSON('/shop_pos/index.php?route=module/cart/ajax_remove_item', {value: value}, function(data, textStatus)  
    {
        console.log('not getting in here');
      //optional stuff to do after success
    });
    console.log(value);
});
```

What would cause the ajax request to not fire

Comment: Add some logs on the server side to check that its not really reaching. also in the 1st ajax call put some logs in the success and error functions...

Comment: I tried and its not getting to the script

Comment: This works fine in Chrome and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/2hGg9/7/

Comment: I figured it out with @Brad response, it was a parseerror on the serverside

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend supplying the `error` option in your first ajax query to see if anything faults.

```
$.ajax({
  .. other options
  error: function(x,t,e){
    console.log('Ajax error');
  }
  .. more options
});
```

Comment: ThaT helped me dissect the problem which was a parseerror on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your variable `value` to something else

Comment: That wouldn't make any difference. `{value: value}` is perfectly valid JavaScript.